# What is the method ".getChildren()" used for in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, methods

For example if I were to add a line of code such as-

```
hbox.getChildren().add(calculateButton);
```

what significance does .getChildren hold and what happens if it not used in a program?

Comment: Since your UI is represented in a tree, all objects that are supposed to be "inside" the hbox are contained in a list called "children". Since you want to add your ``calculateButton`` to your ``hbox``, you add it to the list of children.

Comment: @f1sh Thank you.

Comment: when programming GUIs you can see oft controls holding controls inside of them, those are  in an associative ***parent-children*** relationship..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getChildren` method is used to get the children components(such as checkboxes, buttons etc) in a container.

In your case, `hBox` is a container which can contain buttons, spinners etc. So `getChildren` lists the current components in hBox.

It is basically a list of components currently present in the container. By using `add()` you are adding a new component in that list.